# A broadcast receiver in a widget stops running after many hours

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver

I have, in a widget, a broadcast receiver which works perfectly except that it stops after X hours: it is several hours. It is really tough to debug as the delay is hard to find. I thought that it could be due to the   updatePeriodMillis so I set its value to 1hr = 3600000.

But if I test the BR like after 1hr15min, it still works. It looks like it happens after a much longer delay.

Did I miss something in the doc about the BR? Are they capped on time?

Also I'm not sure that if the BR is not triggered in so many hours then it stops?

Is it the fact that I use it in a widget?

Comment: What are you registering the Receiver for? That is, which broadcasts is it registered for?

Comment: camera availability. but if I were registering for wifi on/off or battery usage wouldn't it be the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "camera availability", but I was checking whether the broadcast is coming from your own app, directly or indirectly; e.g., to handle a Widget click. Anyway, you shouldn't really be registering a Receiver in an `AppWidgetProvider`, if that's what you're doing. `AppWidgetProvider` itself is a `BroadcastReceiver`, and instances of those registered in the manifest aren't meant to live very long.

Comment: if my widget monitors the network changes (as wifi on/off) you are obliged to register a BR?

Comment: Since Nougat, yes, I believe you would have to dynamically register a Receiver for the `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` broadcast. Before that, you can use a statically registered Receiver in the manifest. My point, though, was that an `AppWidgetProvider` isn't a good place to be dynamically registering that Receiver. If you absolutely have to know exactly when connectivity changes, then a foreground `Service` would be preferable. If you just need some task to run whenever a network is available, you can use `JobScheduler` and a `JobService` for that.

Comment: I think I've found the issue: updatePeriodMillis. every schedule I re-register which creates the confusion. I suspected this issue but not sure why when I tested previously it seemed to work. Many thanks for your support especially as it is not the 1st time that you help me! :)